elementary analysis proof verification
Show that if X, Y and Z are convergent sequences, then the sequence $w:=mid\{x_n,y_n,z_n\}$ is convergent.
The attempt:
(1) Suppose $x_n$ goes to x, $y_n$ goes to y, and $z_n$ goes to z. WLOG, assume $x \leq y \leq z$.
(2) There exists an $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies that $x_n \leq y_n \leq z_n$.
(3) Therefore, for $n \geq N$, we have $w:=mid\{x_n,y_n,z_n\}=y_n$, which converges.
(4) Since the tail end of $w_n$ converges, the sequence $w_n$ also converges.
I know, the 2nd step requires extra work, i tried and couldn't show it. However, my intuition tells me it is true...

The difficulty will appear when $y=z$.

You have the right idea, but as you noticed yourself the second step is not true in general.  If you have $x<y<z$ then you can prove the second step.  That is, to prove the second step we let $\delta$ be the minimum gap between consecutive $x,y,z$, and pick $N$ large enough that for $n>N$ the sequences are each within $\delta/2$ of their limits.
On the other hand, if one of the inequalities is not strict and the other one is, then for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists sufficiently large $N$, such that $n>N$ implies $w_n$ is within $\epsilon$ of the repeated value.  That is, for some $N_1$ we have that one of the two sequences (which converge to the repeated value) stays within $\epsilon$ of the repeated value, and for some $N_2$ we have that the other (of those two sequences) does, so we just take $N$ to be the greater of $N_1,N_2$.  Then it does not matter which of the sequences $w_n$ coincides with for a particular value of $n$.
Finally if $x=y=z$, we simply take $N$ to be the greater of $N_1,N_2,N_3$, where one of the sequences stays within $\epsilon$ of the limit for $n>N_1$, another of the sequences stays within $\epsilon$ of the limit for $n>N_2$, and the last stays with within $\epsilon$ of the limit for $n>N_3$.
